# “ImportError: no module named 'bcolz'” after installing with pip

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter

So I'm currently running on Windows 7 and I'm trying to run some jupyter notebook. I use Python 2.7.13 and Anaconda. I did "pip install bcolz" and everything went well, but I still can't import it. I even tried "conda install bcolz" and everything went smooth again but no luck again. I run everything via cygwin and everything just looks good to me.

I've seen many questions like this one here but none really helped me. Reinstall didn't work and other things were too problem specific.
Any idea ? :(

**Edit**(code):

```
C:\Users\NyaHo\courses-master\deeplearning1\nbs\utils.py in <module>()
 20 from scipy.ndimage import imread
 21 from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
---> 22 import bcolz
 23 from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
 24 from sklearn.manifold import TSNE

ImportError: No module named bcolz
```

Also:

```
$ python -V
Python 2.7.13
$ pip --version
pip 8.1.2 from E:\PythonAnaconda\lib\site-packages (python 2.7)
$ conda --version
conda 4.3.22
```

Comment: Please provide code example on how you import it, and the error logs.

Answer (score 1):

The below command got me some progress:

```
conda install -c anaconda bcolz
```

However, I also had to fix permissions on my anaconda install directory (Ubunutu).